# How to get the offset of a field within a device in Linux when calling mmap()

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am currently implementing `mmap()` in a Linux device driver.

Basically, suppose there is a struct called `data` that is already defined. My device's struct is defined as follows,

```
struct test_dev{
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct mutex lock;
    struct data *data;
};
```

In device's `open()` method, `data` is allocated by calling vmalloc(). Suppose I would like to let user call `mmap()` to map to the data field, the user needs to know the `offset` of `data` field:

```
int fd = open("/dev/testdev", O_RDWR);
int ret = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
```

I got stuck when trying to find the offset of `data`.

I looked into the manpage of mmap(), it says

> The contents of a file mapping (as opposed to an anonymous
> mapping; see MAP_ANONYMOUS below), are initialized using length
> bytes starting at offset offset in the file (or other object)
> referred to by the file descriptor fd.

**Q1: Since `data` field is allocated using vmalloc(), it is in high memory, but `test_dev` structure is allocated using kmalloc(), which is in low memory, addr(data) - addr(test_dev) is less than 0. Therefore, we cannot compute the offset in such way. May I know if there is another approach to get the `offset`, so that the user could use this `offset` to `mmap()` to the `data` field?**

**Q2: If instead the `data` field is allocated using `kmalloc()`, will there be any difference between the `vmalloc()` approach?**

In *Linux Device Drivers*, it states that memory addresses returned by `kmalloc()` is also virtual address, and it is located in low memory. I am not sure if using "addr(data) - addr(test_dev)" would work. Based on my own understanding, it is unlikely to work.

Besides, since `kmalloc()` [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/linux-manual-3.16/kmalloc.9.en.html) says `kmalloc()` is the normal method of allocating memory for objects smaller than page size in the kernel, when implementing mmap(), we may not choose to map to the address returned by `kmalloc()` since mmap() maps on a page boundary.

Comment: "the user needs to know the offset of data field". This doesn't seem right at all. The `offset` parameter is not meant for that. If the user wants the data, you don't map `test_dev`, you map whatever `data` is pointing at, and `offset` is an offset from *that*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset is passed to the mmap handler you write in your device driver.  You can treat it as an arbitrary `off_t` parameter that means anything you want.  Just ignore it and always mmap `data`.  Or use it as an offset from the start of `data`, which is probably the most correct semantics for your driver.

The struct you kmalloc()'ed when your driver initialized has nothing to do with mmap.  `offset` is not an offset from the start of this struct.

To mmap vmalloc memory, you need to get each page, since they are not contiguous, and add it to the vma.  See `vmalloc_to_page` and `vm_insert_page`.

Comment: @ TrentP Thank you for your answer. By reading the comment by @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m. , I think I figured out what the offset means - it is what you described in the last sentence of the first paragraph. So I need to directly mmap to data, and let the offset determine the offset within data.

Comment: If this is a custom driver, offset can mean whatever you want.  I don't know its details, but what I and @n have described is a common and logical way to use the offset.  But there's also what one of the uio drivers does, where `offset` is treated as enumeration that selects from different banks, e.g. `offset = 3 * PAGE_SIZE` means map bank 3.  It has no relationship to any memory offsets.